# How can i trim an existing video in android ?

Tags: android, video, trim

i have an activity where i display a video in Video view,Video view takes half of my screen, and i want in the other half to display frame by frame images(thumbnails) and to be able to trim the video in 10-15 seconds.
I have done a lot of research on google but i can't find a solution, please help it is very important ! where can i get a tutorial about this ?

this is how i show video on activity:

```
    video_holder = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.display_video);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ur = intent.getStringExtra("videocrop");
    Uri vid_uri = Uri.parse(ur);
    video_holder.setVideoURI(vid_uri);
    video_holder.start();
```

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-running-samples

Answer (score 1):

Try mp4parser library and you see ringdroid for audio